# Loading grid only after "all" the data stores have loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, rally

I have this code that loads a data store for all stories that contain each of the names from an array.

```
var prefix_set = [list of names]
for(var i=0;i<prefix_set.length;i++)
   _get_stories_of_feature(prefix_set[i]) //this function creates a data store
```

I am storing all the data into a global array and creating a data store which is passed to a grid in the end. The problem is that my grid loads up with incomplete data (the grid loads up even before all the data has been loaded into the global array).

Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
items:[{ xtype: 'container', itemId: 'print_button_box', padding: 5},{xtype: 'container', itemId: 'grid_box'}],
count: 0,
globalStore: null,
totalDataLength: 0,
gridCounter: 0,
launch: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.globalStore = null;
    this.gridCounter = 0;
    this.totalDataLength=0;
    this.count = 0;
    this._addPrintButton();
     list = [];
    //Write app code here
    var prefix_set = ["Epic:","Arch:","Refa:","Innov:","Spike:","Producer:","Dependency:","Consumer:"];
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<prefix_set.length;i++){

        this._get_stories_of_feature(prefix_set[i],prefix_set.length,i);

    }

},
_addPrintButton: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.down('#print_button_box').add( { 
        xtype: 'rallybutton', 
        itemId: 'print_button',
        text: 'CSV',
        disabled: false,
        handler: function() {
           console.log('globalStore ',me.globalStore);

            me.exportGrid(me.globalStore);

        }
    });
},
_onClickExport: function () {

     if (document.getElementById('grid_box')) {

        //Ext.getBody().mask('Exporting Tasks...');
        console.log('inside export');
        setTimeout(function () {
            var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-' +
                'microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>' +
                '<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>' +
                '{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
                '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}' +
                '</table></body></html>';

            var base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            var format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };
            var table = document.getElementById('grid_box');
            console.log("Exporting table ",table);
            var excel_data = '<tr>';
            Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<span .*?x-column-header-text.*?>.*?<\/span>/gm), function (column_header_span) {
                excel_data += (column_header_span.replace(/span/g, 'td'));
            });
            excel_data += '</tr>';
            Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<tr class="x-grid-row.*?<\/tr>/gm), function (line) {
                excel_data += line.replace(/[^\011\012\015\040-\177]/g, '>>');
            });
            console.log("Excel data ",excel_data);
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: excel_data};
            window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64(format(template, ctx));
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
        }, 500);
    }else{
        console.log("grid_box does not exist");
    }
},
tableToExcel: function(){
    var me = this;
    console.log("Global store ",me.globalStore);
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }); };

     return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML};
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  };
},
_createStore: function(){
    var me = this;
    //var f = [{property: 'UserStories', operator: '!=', value: null}];
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        autoLoad: true,
        model: "PortfolioItem/Feature",
        limit: 10000,
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','UserStories','c_DIteration','c_DPSI'],


        listeners:{
            load: function(store,data,success){

                console.log("Store ",store);
                var data_length = data.length;
                console.log('Data length is '+data.length);
                Ext.Array.each(data,function(item){
                    if(item.get('UserStories')==null){
                        store.remove(item);
                    }else{
                        var data = {
                            id: item.get("FormattedID"),
                            name: item.get("Name"),
                            UserStories: item.get("UserStories")._type,
                            DIteration: item.get("c_DIteration"),
                            DPSI: item.get("c_DPSI")
                        };
                        //list.push(data);
                    }


                    me._get_stories_of_feature(item.get("ObjectID"),item.get("Name"),data_length);
                });

            },
            scope: this
        }
    });
},
_showGrid: function(store){
    var me = this;
    if(!this.grid){
        this.grid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid',{
            store: store,
            columnCfgs:[
                {text: 'Feature', dataIndex: 'name'},
                {text: 'FormattedID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID'},
                {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'UserStories'},
                {text: 'Release', dataIndex: 'Release'},
                {text: 'Iteration', dataIndex: 'Iteration'},
                {text: 'DIteration', dataIndex: 'DIteration'},
                {text: 'DPSI', dataIndex: 'DPSI'},
                {text: 'Schedule State', dataIndex: 'ScheduleState'},
                {text: 'Task Remaining Total', dataIndex: 'TaskRemainingTotal'},
                {text: 'Owner', dataIndex: 'Owner'},,
                {text: 'Project', dataIndex: 'Project'},
                {text: 'Unscheduled', dataIndex: 'Unscheduled'}
            ]
        });
        me.globalStore = this.grid;
        this.down('#grid_box').add(this.grid);
    }
},
_get_stories_of_feature: function(name,length,k){
    var me = this;
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        autoLoad: true,
        model: "HierarchicalRequirement",
        limit: 10000,
        fetch: ['Name','ObjectID','FormattedID','Parent','Feature','TaskRemainingTotal','c_DIteration','c_DPSI','DragAndDropRank','Release','Iteration','Project','Owner','ScheduleState'],
        sorters:[{
            property: 'DragAndDropRank', direction: 'ASC'
        ,},{property: 'Project', direction: 'ASC'}],
        filters:[{
            property: 'Name', operator: 'contains', value: name
        },{
            property: 'ScheduleState', operator: '!=', value: 'Accepted'
        }],
        pageSize: 5000,
        listeners:{
            load: function(store,data,success){

                var data_length = data.length;

                if(data_length>0){
                    console.log("Total stories ",data_length);
                    for(var i=0;i<data_length;i++){
                        console.log("Data length for ",k," is ",data_length);

                        console.log("Data i ",data[i]);
                            me.totalDataLength++;
                            var flag;
                            var iteration=""; var release="";
                            var fid = "",fname="";
                            var owner="";
                            if(data[i].data.Feature!=null && (data[i].data.Feature.c_DIteration==null || data[i].data.Feature.c_DIteration.toString().indexOf("*")!=-1))
                                 flag = "YES";
                            else flag = "NO";

                            if(data[i].data.Iteration!=null){
                                iteration = data[i].data.Iteration._refObjectName;
                            }
                            if(data[i].data.Release!=null){
                                release = data[i].data.Release._refObjectName;
                            }
                            if(data[i].data.Owner!=null){
                                owner = data[i].data.Owner._refObjectName;
                            }
                            if(data[i].data.Feature!=null){
                                fid = data[i].data.Feature.FormattedID;
                                fname = data[i].data.Feature.Name; 
                            }
                            var element = {
                                name: fid+":"+fname,
                                UserStories: data[i].data.Name,
                                Project: data[i].data.Project._refObjectName,
                                Owner: owner,
                                FormattedID: data[i].data.FormattedID,
                                Iteration: iteration,
                                TaskRemainingTotal: parseInt(data[i].data.TaskRemainingTotal),
                                Release: release,
                                ScheduleState: data[i].data.ScheduleState,
                                DIteration: data[i].data.c_DIteration,
                                DPSI: data[i].data.c_DPSI,
                                Unscheduled: flag                                   
                            };
                            list.push(element);

                            console.log("me count is ",me.count);
                            console.log("Found ",data[i].data);

                            me.count++;
                    }
                }
                console.log("Total Data Length is ",me.totalDataLength);
                console.log("k is ",k," and length is ",length);
                if(k==length-1){
                    console.log("Building store");
                    //once all the stories and feature data is computed
                    var myStore = Ext.create("Rally.data.custom.Store",{
                    data: list,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageSize: me.totalDataLength,

                });
                me._showGrid(myStore);  
                }


            }

        }
    });
    me.gridCounter++;

},
 exportGrid: function(grid) {
    if (Ext.isIE) {
        this._ieToExcel(grid);

    } else {
        var data = this._getCSV(grid);

        window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    }
},

_escapeForCSV: function(string) {
    if (string.match(/,/)) {
        if (!string.match(/"/)) {
            string = '"' + string + '"';
        } else {
            string = string.replace(/,/g, ''); // comma's and quotes-- sorry, just loose the commas
        }
    }
    return string;
},

_getFieldText: function(fieldData) {
    var text;

    if (fieldData == null || fieldData == undefined) {
        text = '';

    } else if (fieldData._refObjectName && !fieldData.getMonth) {
        text = fieldData._refObjectName;

    } else if (fieldData instanceof Date) {
        text = Ext.Date.format(fieldData, this.dateFormat);

    } else if (!fieldData.match) { // not a string or object we recognize...bank it out
        text = '';

    } else {
        text = fieldData;
    }

    return text;
},

_getFieldTextAndEscape: function(fieldData) {
    var string  = this._getFieldText(fieldData);

    return this._escapeForCSV(string);
},

_getCSV: function (grid) {
    var cols    = grid.columns;
    var store   = grid.store;
    var data    = '';
console.log("Grid.Store is ",grid.store);
    var that = this;
    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(col.text) + ',';
        }
    });
    data += "\n";

    store.each(function(record) {
        var entry       = record.getData();
        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];

                data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(text) + ',';
            }
        });
        data += "\n";
    });

    return data;
},

_ieGetGridData : function(grid, sheet) {
    var that            = this;
    var resourceItems   = grid.store.data.items;
    var cols            = grid.columns;

    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            console.log('header: ', col.text);
            sheet.cells(1,colIndex + 1).value = col.text;
        }
    });

    var rowIndex = 2;
    grid.store.each(function(record) {
        var entry   = record.getData();

        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];
                var value       = that._getFieldText(text);

                sheet.cells(rowIndex, colIndex+1).value = value;
            }
        });
        rowIndex++;
    });
},

_ieToExcel: function (grid) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        var  xlApp, xlBook;
        try {
            xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
        } catch (e) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'For the export to work in IE, you have to enable a security setting called "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe" from Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level..."');
            return;
        }

        xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate;
        var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet;
        xlApp.visible = true; 

       this._ieGetGridData(grid, XlSheet);
       XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
    }
}



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the code [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428560/using-collection-summaries-for-multi-select-fields),  where Mark uses promises, and builds three separate [Rally.data.wsapi.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Store)s and only after all the data is there `_makeGrid(resultArray)` is called.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding to my question, my query is really simple, I have a set of strings and I get those stories containing those strings and having ScheduleState!=Accepted. When view the user stories in Rally with these filters I get 1043 results, but when I run my app, I just get 830 results. I am making sure I am in the same project in both cases. Can you think of any reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: You are welcome. You may be in the same project in Rally (in UI) but you are scoping up or down, so items form child or parent projects show up in the current project. You may use limit: Infinity. Are you an older release of appsdk2 or the latest rc2? Finally, test your query directly in WS API doc and compare to results in UI and from your app.

Comment: The issue in my opinion here is that there are a lot of projects about 500+ when I scope down from my current project. The query does not pull data from some projects.